# has_and_belongs_to_many or has_many for user/group relationship?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, has-and-belongs-to-many, has-one

I'm working on a Rails 3.1 app that has the following models:

**User:**

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_and_belongs_to_many :groups
  has_many :ownerships, :class_name => 'Group'
end
```

**Group:**

```
class Group < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_and_belongs_to_many :users
  has_one :owner, :class_name => 'User'
end
```

There's a join table between them, and the groups table also has a "user_id" column. I would expect to be able to write this in my groups_controller.rb

```
@group = Group.find(params[:id])
foo = @group.owner
```

but when I do I'm presented with the following error:

```
Mysql2::Error: Unknown column 'users.group_id' in 'where clause': SELECT  `users`.* FROM `users`  WHERE `users`.`group_id` = 1 LIMIT 1
```

I don't understand why it's even looking for that column. Any help would be appreciated!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

make sure your groups table has a user_id or owner_id column and try this:

```
  class Group < ActiveRecord::Base
    has_and_belongs_to_many :users
    belongs_to :owner, :class_name => 'User'
  end
```

Comment: Thanks antpaw. This seems to be a step forward (as it's not giving me MySQL errors any more), but it's still returning nil for @group.owner.inspect.

Comment: are you sure that column owner_id is not empty and the user with that id lives in the user table?

Comment: You're right! I actually had "user_id" instead of "owner_id." BUT now when I try to come in from the other side (@user.ownerships.inspect) it's looking for the column "user_id" again.

P.S. I updated my User model in the original question.

Comment: maybe adding :foreign_key option will help, sorry im not sure

Comment: That was it exactly! Thanks so much! :)